# How to trigger SharePoint workflow with Like/Unlike clicks for Team Discussion

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I created a workflow for a team discussion list, and enabled the rating system. I set the WF to be triggered when Item is changed. Since users could like Like/Unlike the items, it in turn changes the "Number of Likes" field. I assume the item is changed so it should trigger the WF. However this doesn't seem to be the case, the WF is only triggered when I change some other fields like Title for example.

Is Like/Unlike (Number of Likes) a separate algorithm when SP checking if an item is "Changed". If so, any way I could have the WF be trigger on the item if someone "Liked" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, clicking "Like/unlike" doesn't change the item, its modified will not be changed. So your workflow will not be triggered.

There is no OOB way to trigger a workflow via Like/Unlike, as a workaround, you can use try to jQuery code to monitor the event of Like/Unlike and trigger your workflow.